# Custom select DataTable Columns in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I would like to select the columns of `DataTable` that start with a given letter in C#. I have to do it using `Sort Property`. I only found how to sort them ascending or descending.

The result of sort should be equivalent to the sql select statement with `LIKE 'l%'`, `l` being given as a parameter. I could extract first letter using Substring, but how can I use it? Thanks.

```
DataView dv= employees.DefaultView;
dv.Sort="ColumnName asc";
employees = dv.ToTable();
```

P.S.: Also found about `RowFilter` property, but I need to use 'Sort'.

Sorry for not being very clear the first time.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `Sort` property and can't use LINQ? Why do you need it at all since `Sort="ColumnName asc"` orders by the complete field including the first letter. So the difference should be marginal.

Comment: After sorting, I need to select only those which begin with the given letter. The usage of `Sort` is a requirement, that's why I'm looking for a solution which contains it.

Comment: Then this requirement is pretty pointless since you want to sort records by the first letter which all start with the same letter anyway. However, i have edited my answer to show how to change the LINQ-query to filter records.

Comment: It isn't actually a sort. It's more like a select.

Comment: Don't get me wrong but you should clarify first what you actually need. And you should mention that in the question to prevent that people take time to provide a solution to the wrong requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LINQ-To-DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387003(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
employees = employees.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(row => row.Field<string>("ColumnName").FirstOrDefault())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq` at the top of the file.

Maybe you find query syntax more readable:

```
var rows = from row in employees.AsEnumerable()
           let value = row.Field<string>("ColumnName")
           orderby value.FirstOrDefault()
           select row;
employees = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

**UPDATE**: *"After sorting, I need to select only those which begin with the given letter"*

Then you probably want to filter records, therefore use `Enumerable.Where`:

So either:

```
employees = employees.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("ColumnName").StartsWith("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    .OrderBy(row => row.Field<string>("ColumnName").FirstOrDefault())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

or (same in query syntax):

```
var rows = from row in employees.AsEnumerable()
           let value = row.Field<string>("ColumnName")
           where value.StartsWith("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) // for example
           orderby value.FirstOrDefault()
           select row;
employees = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

However, now the `orderby` is pretty pointless since you want to order records by the first letter which start all with the same letter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

here an old DataTable select and sort wrapper i used to use. now i'm using another class that transform an datatable into custom object and can easily use linq.

```
public static class CTableManager
{
    public static DataTable Select(DataTable dt, string sFilter)
    {
        DataTable dtResult = dt.Clone();

        try
        {
            dtResult = dt.Select(sFilter).CopyToDataTable();
        }
        catch { }

        return dtResult;
    }

    public static DataTable Sort(DataTable dt, string sOrder)
    {
         DataTable dtResult = dt.Clone();

         try
         {
             dt.DefaultView.Sort = sOrder;

             dtResult = dt.DefaultView.ToTable().Copy();
         }
         catch { }

         return dtResult;
    }

     public static DataTable SelectAndSort(DataTable dt, string sFilter, string sOrder)
    {
        DataTable dtResult = dt.Copy();

        if (sFilter != string.Empty)
        {
            dtResult = Select(dtResult, sFilter);
        }

        if (sOrder != string.Empty)
        {
            dtResult = Sort(dtResult, sOrder);
        }

        return dtResult;
    }
}
```

usage :

A normal where filter in SQL

```
var myResult = CTableManager.Select(dtSource,"itemDesc like '%plastic%' AND Price > 25.97");
```

A sort again SQL like

```
 var myResult = CTableManager.Sort(dtSource,"Price DESC, Quantity ASC");
```

and obviously both

```
var myResult = CTableManager.SelectAndSort(dtSource,"itemDesc like '%plastic%' AND Price > 25.97", "Price DESC, Quantity ASC");
```